# Specify type of instance variables using python 2 type comments

Tags: python, python-2.7, mypy, type-hinting

I am trying to specify the type for an instance variable using PEP 484's [python 2 syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#suggested-syntax-for-python-2-7-and-straddling-code). However, I haven't found any way to add types without initializing the variable in python 2, equivalent to the following python 3:

```
value: int
```

My normal work around for this is to declare the type of the variable in `__init__` when instantiating the variable. However, this doesn't work for Protocols where the type of the instance variable should be part of the Protocol (types in `__init__` seem to not count). Here's an example in Python 3 where I use a default implementation:

```
from typing_extensions import Protocol
class A(Protocol):
    value: int

    def get_value(self) -> int:
        return self.value
```

This would then highlight errors if `value` isn't initialized properly:

```
class B(A):
    pass
B()  # error: Cannot instantiate abstract class 'B' with abstract attribute 'value'
```

However, converting this to python 2 type comments fails to pass mypy. It gives the same error with or without the `__init__` declaration.

```
class A(Protocol):
    def __init__(self):
        # type: () -> None
        self.value = 0  # type: int
    def get_value(self):
        # type: () -> int
        return self.value  # error: "A" has no attribute "value"
```

Is there some special syntax for declaring variable types without initializing them in python 2?

Comment: I guess that's why Protocol is in `typing_extensions` in 2.7 rather than `typing`.

Comment: @BoarGules This is an extremely unhelpful comment because it implies this is an explicit decision made in mypy. It seems much more like a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mypy's protocols use **class variables** to define attributes. Otherwise mypy does not make a particularly fine distinction between class vs instance variables. Taking these two things together, you can write code like the following:

```
from typing_extensions import Protocol

class A(Protocol):
    value = None  # type: int

    def get_value(self):
        # type: () -> int
        return self.value

# below here it's just to validate that the protocol works

class B(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        # type: (int) -> None
        self.value = value

    def get_value(self):
        # type: () -> int
        return self.value


a = B(42)  # type: A
```

Comment: This works, to my surprise! `A.value` is a class variable not an instance variable; however, mypy seems to also accept objects with instance variables as implementing `A`. Changing B to have `def __init__(self): self.value = 42` (instance variable) typechecks fine, which was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: If you update your answer to use an instance variable in `B` I'll accept this.

Comment: Done! I think in the process of updating this answer I started to understand the question better.